# ss not showing all ports being listened on

Tags: netstat, iproute

After doing a `ssh -fND 1080 localhost`, ssh will listen on port 1080 to provide the SOCKS service:

```
box:~$ netstat -ln|grep 1080
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:1080                :::*                    LISTEN     
box:~$
```

`ss` seems to think otherwise:

```
box:~$ ss -l|grep 1080
box:~$
```

So **how can I use `ss` to check whether 1080 is being listened on or not?**

Some more info on my setup:

```
box:~$ uname -a
Linux box 4.3.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-5 (2016-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux

box:~$ ss -v
ss utility, iproute2-ss151103
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might help you,

```
ss -tupln | grep 1080
```

Comment: It worked, and what made the difference was the option `-n, --numeric Do not try to resolve service names.`

Comment: I needed the -l as well. "-l, --listening
              Display only listening sockets (these are omitted by default)."

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky I had the same issue. Guess it has to do with our names hahaha